# Streaming upload to S3 using pre-signed url fails with 403

Tags: node.js, amazon-s3, request

Uploading a binary file to a pre-signed S3 url using nodeJs and request succeeds when the body is presented as a buffer, but fails with 403 when presented as a stream. Docs indicate that body can be a buffer or stream.

```
// this succeeds
request({
  url: uploadUrl,
  headers: {
    'Content-Length':length
  }
  method: 'put',
  body: fs.readFileSync(name),
},(err,resp,body)=>{
..
})

// this fails with 403
request({
  url: uploadUrl,
  method: 'put',
  headers: {
    'Content-Length':length
  }
  body: fs.createReadStream(name),
},(err,resp,body)=>{
..
})
```